# "Error: Nothing to do" While installing GIT using yum

Tags: linux, git, installation, redhat

I got below error while Installing `GIT` from `version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Command: `sudo yum install git`

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
No package git available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Command : `yum repolist`

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
repolist: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS**

1. Install the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux normally called as `EPEL` using the below command

> yum install epel-release

2.After this,You would notice that the following repository files are added to the yum.repos.d directory in your server.

> ls -lh /etc/yum.repos.d/

3. Then proceed your command.